# how to check if a user has clicked close in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, notifications

There I have coded a default **HTML5** desktop notification and when I close the notification and refresh the page the notification comes back again I want the notification to never come back when I close it

heres my code

```
 function notifyMe() {
  if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    alert("This browser does not support system notifications");
  }
  else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    notify();
  }
  else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
    Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
      if (permission === "granted") {
        notify();
      }
    });
  }

  function notify() {
    var notification = new Notification('TITLE OF NOTIFICATION', {
      icon: 'http://carnes.cc/jsnuggets_avatar.jpg',
      body: "Hey! You are on notice!",
    });

    notification.onclick = function () {
      window.open("http://carnes.cc");      
    };
    setTimeout(notification.close.bind(notification), 7000); 
  }

}
notifyMe();
```

hope someone could help me

ThankYou

Comment: not any were really should I take it out for my problem to be solved

Comment: `Web Storage` maybe can help you. [Web Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: could you please give me your version of my code using web storage im not that good in javascript my self

Comment: `window.localStorage` and `window.sessionStorage` are different type of storage read from this link [Web Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) its fairly easy to understand. you should set a `key` that user has clicked the notification, then at first place check if `storage` has your `key` don't show notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of already shown notifications into `localStorage`. As shown in following example:

```
function notify() {
    const notifications = localStorage.getItem('notifications', ['TITLE OF NOTIFICATION']) || [];
    const notifiedIndex = notifications.indexOf('TITLE OF NOTIFICATION');
    if (notifiedIndex > -1) {
        var notification = new Notification('TITLE OF NOTIFICATION', {
            icon: 'http://carnes.cc/jsnuggets_avatar.jpg',
            body: "Hey! You are on notice!",
        });

        notification.onclick = function() {
            window.open("http://carnes.cc");
        };
        setTimeout(notification.close.bind(notification), 7000);
        notifications.push('TITLE OF NOTIFICATION');
        localStorage.setItem('notifications', notifications)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do with localStorage.

```js
function notifyMe() {
  if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    alert("This browser does not support system notifications");
  }
  else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    notify();
  }
  else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
    Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
      if (permission === "granted") {
        notify();
      }
    });
  }

  function notify() {
      if (localStorage.close) {
          return false;
      }


    var notification = new Notification('TITLE OF NOTIFICATION', {
      icon: 'http://carnes.cc/jsnuggets_avatar.jpg',
      body: "Hey! You are on notice!",
    });

    notification.onclick = function () {
      window.open("http://carnes.cc");
    };

    notification.onclose = function () {
        localStorage.close = true;
    };

    setTimeout(notification.close.bind(notification), 7000);
  }

}
notifyMe();
```

Comment: hello @VolkanYilmaz your code works when I close the notification and refresh the page the notification does not come back thats all good but when I go on another computer the notification does'nt come up at all do you know what the problem is?

Comment: sorry but did not understand